# Event by clicking Checkbox

Tags: jquery

How do, when click a checkbox, in `var check='';` will be added - `okay`,
and if click again,`okay` will be removed.

How it make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var check = "";
$("#yourcheckbox").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        check = "okay";
    }
    else {
        check = "";
    }
});
```

This does exactly what you ask, but the solution posted by @Rikudo is better if you can live without `check` having to contain "okay".

Answer (score 2):

```
var check = false;
console.log(check);
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
    check = $(this).is(':checked');
    console.log(check);
});
```

Will set the variable to `true` or `false` depending on the state.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/6mfRL/)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
var check;
$('#checkbox').change(function() {this.checked ? check = 'okay' : check = '';})
```